# Django Form Can't Filter Foreign Key on Dropdown

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

**Edit: Rewrote Description for clarity**

I have a "CustomUser" class that I got from an all-auth tutorial [(Django All-Auth Tutorial](https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial-custom-user-model/)) and I have user as a foreign key in each model, which works as intended, only showing records pertaining to the current logged in user to that specific user.

For example:

**EDUCATION MODEL (Works Correctly Here)**

```
class Education(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    EducationInstitutionName = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Institution Name'), max_length=100, default=None)
    EducationLevel = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Education Level'), choices=EDUCATIONLEVEL, max_length=100, default=None)
    EducationStartDate = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Education Start Date'), default=None)
    EducationEndDate = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Education End Date'), default=None)
    EducationCaoCode = models.CharField(choices=CAO_CODE, max_length=100, default=None)
    EducationDesc = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Education Description'), max_length=250, default=None)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.EducationInstitutionName
```

This works perfectly and I am achieving what is needed.

The issue arises when I have a table comprised of Foreign Keys which is the focal point of my application which takes the constituent parts of a CV and allows you to combine them to make a CV of interchangable sections.

**CV MODEL (Only model I have which is composed of Foreign Keys)**

```
class Cv(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    CvName = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('CvName'), max_length=100, default=None)
    CvEducation = models.ForeignKey(Education, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CvSkills = models.ForeignKey(Skills, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CvWorkExperience = models.ForeignKey(WorkExperience, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.CvName
```

**CV FORM**

This is where I'm hitting the issue - I want to filter the fields to only show records of Education, Skills and Work Experience for the current user - at the moment the dropdown shows every record in existence for the Education, Skills and Work Experience models rather than those ONLY pertaining to the current logged in user.

```
class CvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cv
        fields = ('CvName', 'CvEducation', 'CvSkills', 'CvWorkExperience')

# TRYING TO FILTER BY CURRENT USER
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CvForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(user)
        self.fields['CvEducation'].queryset = Education.objects.filter(user=user)
        self.fields['CvSkills'].queryset = Education.objects.filter(user=user)
        self.fields['CvWorkExperience'].queryset = Education.objects.filter(user=user)


    def save(self, commit=True):
        cv = super(CvForm, self).save(commit=False)
        cv.user = self.request.user
        cv.CvName = self.cleaned_data['CvName']
        cv.CvEducation = self.cleaned_data['CvEducation']
        cv.CvSkills = self.cleaned_data['CvSkills']
        cv.CvWorkExperience = self.cleaned_data['CvWorkExperience']
        cv.save()
        return cv
```

**CV LIST VIEW (This - correctly - only shows *completed* CV records associated with the current logged in user)**

```
class CvList(ListView):
    model = Cv
    fields = ['CvName', 'CvEducation', 'CvSkills', 'CvWorkExperience']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Cv_list')

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_ids = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=self.request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)
        if user_ids:
            for uid in user_ids:
                return Cv.objects.filter(user__id=uid)
        else:
            return Cv.objects.all()
```

**CV CREATE VIEW**

```
class CvCreate(CreateView):
    model = Cv
    fields = ['CvName', 'CvEducation', 'CvSkills', 'CvWorkExperience']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Cv_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CvCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_ids = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=self.request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)
        if user_ids:
            for uid in user_ids:
                return Cv.objects.filter(user__id=uid)
        else:
            return Cv.objects.all()
```

This gives me...
[Dropdown showing the whole Education table rather than filtering by Current User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSxo.png)

In this image as I'm logged in as *John Doe* I should not be able to see the record - "James Edu" as that is associated with a different user *James*.

This occurs in all three of the fields I have with Foreign Keys - CvEducation, CvSkills and CvWorkExperience

Comment: So the problem is you want to get their educations in the dropdown but you are getting the users themselves instead? Or what are you trying to filter?

Comment: Apologies, to clarify - I am getting the Education passed in but it is showing every record for Education rather than just those associated with the current user. It is working for all of the rest of the models - Education, Work Experience and Skills - but the CV model is made up of ForeignKeys from those models and the same filtering is not working for that.

Comment: It's still a bit vague for me. Are you looking for something like `education = Education.objects.filter(user=current_user)`? Could you post your view code?

Comment: Apologies, updated description for clarity

Comment: Solved - See Description

Answer (score 1):

Fixed eventually (in a very roundabout way):

**FORMS INIT METHOD**

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_arguments = kwargs.get('initial', None)
        initial_arguments_list = list(initial_arguments.values())
        user_id = initial_arguments_list[0]
        super(CvForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['CvEducation'].queryset = Education.objects.filter(user__id=user_id)
        self.fields['CvSkills'].queryset = Skills.objects.filter(user__id=user_id)
        self.fields['CvWorkExperience'].queryset = WorkExperience.objects.filter(user__id=user_id)
```

**CREATE VIEW**

```
class CvCreate(CreateView):
    model = Cv
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Cv_list')
    form_class = CvForm
    exclude = ['user']

    def get_initial(self):
        self.initial.update({ 'created_by': self.request.user.id })
        return self.initial
```